# sqlite3 create table - OperationalError: no such column: nan

Tags: python, sqlite, nan, create-table

A script inserts any number of tables correctly except the following, which
follows the same format as the other tables that have been created succesfully. I am not sure why it is identifying a `nan` column.

```
create_wealth_income_top_decile ="""
CREATE TABLE wealth_income_top_decile(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "year" INT,
    "income_top_10" REAL,
    "wealth_top_10" REAL
                                    );
                                """                                    

cursor.execute(create_wealth_income_top_decile)

""" Use for loop to populate table with tuples from csv """
for i in wealth_inc_data.to_records(index=False):
    insertinfo_2 ="""
        INSERT INTO wealth_income_top_decile(
                                        year, 
                                        income_top_10,
                                        wealth_top_10
                                        )
                                        VALUES
                                        """+str(i) + ';'
    cursor.execute(insertinfo_2)                                    

cursor.close()
CONN.commit()
```

This is the error I get:

> File "create_db.py", line 67, in
>
> cursor.execute(insertinfo_2)
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: nan

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRwuQ.png)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in my previous (deleted) comments! Apparently one (or more) of the values from the csv is missing, and is translated to (imputed by) a nan value. Not sure how you are reading the CSV, what `wealth_inc_data` is? But maybe you could try filling the gaps with zeroes or similar, depending on your interpretation of the data.

Comment: Similar things might happen if the data has some other "dirt", like a wrong decimal separator or suffer from a similar, perhaps difficult-to-notice, anomaly, that fails the string to numeric conversion for the reader.

Comment: If so, and if it comes via Pandas `read_csv`, you could give calling `wealth_inc_data.fillna(0)` a shot, someplace before inserting the records, just to see if it fits the problem.

Comment: (* of course, nan is then taken as a string without quotes, that would the refer to the column "nan" by name in the SQL world, if I understand the error message and other bits correctly)

Comment: When debugging SQL statement, always inspect (i.e. output, print, log, watch) the value of the command string to ensure the SQL is formatted properly.  In your case that means not only outputting the value of `insertinfo_2` before calling cursor.execute, but it also means outputting the value of `str(i)` since that is used to construct `insertinfo_2`.  Not only should that be done as part of your own debugging, you should present such information in the question.  Otherwise we have no idea what you are actually trying to execute on the database!  It's just guesswork right now.

Comment: But even without knowing exactly what `str(i)` contains, the INSERT statement looks incorrect because the value list after `VALUES` should be wrapped in parenthesis.  Does the value of `str(i)` also include those parenthesis?  Does it include a properly formatted comma-separated list of values?

Comment: My guess is that whatever code populates `str(i)` is incorrectly importing the csv data, perhaps code that intends to import a number but instead got invalid data so it is storing NaN (Not-a-Number) value.  But you don't share that code, so again it is just a bunch of guesswork. If you have the code, then share it to make the problem definitive.  Showing an image of the data is only a small part of necessary information to debug this issue.  When having problems with CSV, you should inspect a CSV file using a text editor, not a spreadsheet since it does its own manipulation when it imports it.

Comment: Thank you for confirming the problem is with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I inserted NAN values to db, some of our operations were converting integer values to nan before inserting to db.

If your db column do not support nan or inf for int or real value do not insert these to db.